# Custom UIView on iPhone, should look like UIPopover

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, popover

my goal is to create a simple popover view over a bar button in my tool bar. So apparently Apple doesn't want me to create this on my iPhone. But i already saw something familiar on other apps. 
So instead of using the UIPopOver thing from Apple, i like to create an UIView which appears when the bar button is clicked. And disappears when it is clicked again. It would be over the top if i also could create the little arrow which points to the button (you know which arrow i mean :D). But this is not relevant at this time. I just want to create this "popover appears and disappears with the same button". My "solution" right know is not a solution:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
     UIView *myPopOverView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 25, 500, 250)]; 

     myPopOverView.alpha = 0.0;
     myPopOverView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
     myPopOverView.layer.borderWidth = 1.5f;
     myPopOverView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

     UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
     [button addTarget:self
                action:@selector(testNSLog)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     [button setTitle:@"Show myPopOverView" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     button.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 30);
     [myPopOverView addSubview:button];

     [self.view addSubview:myPopOverView];

     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
        [myPopOverView setAlpha:1.0];
     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
}
```

So i don't have a clue on how to do that with this code fragment. It appears right away as i want. But i don't know how to create this toggle. I tried with a simple Bool-If-Toggle, but it didn't work. And i don't really know how to remove it from my view either.
Can you guys help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i solved it.

i defined a UIView in the .h-File and instantiate it in ViewDidLoad, then i did:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    if (showedOptions == NO) {
        [self.view addSubview:self.popoverView];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
            [self.popoverView setAlpha:1.0];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];

        showedOptions = YES;
        return;
    } else {
        showedOptions = NO;
        [self.popoverView removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```